# How to add extra subtitles to celll

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, subtitle

Is there any way for me to add a subtitle below the cell.textLabel as well as a the label '8 fans' on the right as seen below? My understanding is that the standard cell only provides on format and one detailedTextLabel (either subtitle or text on the right). Is there any libraries or efficient way that I can do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you will have to use your custom cells (meaning writing your own class of UITableViewCell). Designing it's view and then connecting this with your TableViewController.

For custom cells you can read this:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

Comment: No need, you can add labels etc to the contentView without having to subclass.

Comment: You don't have to use custom cells for extra labels on your cells but you will get much cleaner code when you do it that way.

Comment: This means I have to customize all the elements in the cell as all the alignment will be gone (if I use the standard ones)

Answer (score 0):

You can add any subviews you like to one of the standard cells, add your label to the contentView property of the cell.